# Como adicionar itens em um dicionário sem sobrepor mantendo o item anterior

Tags: dicionário, inserir

Saudações!!

Com o código abaixo, ao instanciar um funcionário e depois iniciar o cadastro de horas trabalhadas informando o mês e quantidade de horas, inserindo Janeiro:

func01 = Funcionario('Joao','joao@email.com') ==> ok

func01.horas_trabalhadas('janeiro',270) ==> ok

resultado: dict_items([('janeiro', {'horas': 270})])

Quando vou inserir fevereiro:

func01.horas_trabalhadas('fevereiro',220)

resultado: dict_items([('fevereiro', {'horas': 220})])

Quando busco imprimir o dicionário:

func01.imprime_meses()

resultado: fevereiro {'horas': 220}

Ou seja, estou entendendo que todos os meses que forem inseridos serão gravados por cima do mês anterior.
Como eu faço para gravar de Janeiro a Dezembro como 12 itens desse dicionário?

class Funcionario:

```
def __init__(self, nome, email):
    self.nome = nome
    self.email = email
    
def horas_trabalhadas(self, mes , horas):
    self.mes = mes
    self.horas = horas
    self.cadastro_mes = {}
    self.cadastro_temp = {'horas' : self.horas}
    self.cadastro_mes[self.mes] = self.cadastro_temp
    print(self.cadastro_mes.items())
    
def imprime_meses(self):
    for key, value in self.cadastro_mes.items():
        print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Entre outros erros, você está redefinindo self.cadastro_mes como vazio a cada chamada do método horas_trabalhadas(). A linha

self.cadastro_mes = {}

deveria ser movida para `__init__()`, que cria a classe e é executado apenas uma vez.